# htaccess proxy to node app

Tags: node.js, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to proxy subdomain to node application which is running on port 3000. It proxies requests to files e.g subdomain.domain.com/jquery.js. It works fine and shows file served by node. But when I try to access the root of subdomain then I guess apache tries to find index.php and fails with message `Cannot GET /index.php`. How can I make it work so it will serve whatever provided by node app?

my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:3000/$1 [P,L] 
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:3000/ [P,L] 
RewriteEngine On
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
DirectoryIndex disabled
```

worked out

Comment: This is the only thing that fixed my problem after googling for ages. Running a node application on a subdomain using a2hosting shared hosting.

Comment: yes thank you! this worked for me as well, exact same situation.

Comment: Is there no other solution for that?